# In a trait, what is the type for a Fn that accepts all lifetimes?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm building a pipelining tool, and this is my main trait:

```rust
trait Transform<A, B> {
    fn transform(&self, input: A, out: &dyn Fn(B));
}
```

which works out nicely for owned values, e.g.

```rust
struct Repeat { times: usize }

impl<A: Clone> Transform<A, A> for Repeat {
    fn transform(&self, input: A, out: &dyn Fn(A)) {
        std::iter::repeat(input)
            .take(self.times)
            .for_each(|v| (out)(v))
    }
}
```

This does not work if `B` is a borrow of `A`.

In this contrived example (a more realistic case is transforming a `Read` into `tar::Entry<'a, R>`..):

```rust
use std::io::{Stdin, StdinLock};

struct Lock { }

impl Transform<Stdin, StdinLock> for Lock {
    fn transform(&self, input: Stdin, out: &dyn Fn(StdinLock)) {
        (out)(input.lock())
    }
}
```

```
error[E0053]: method `transform` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> min.rs:25:5
   |
4  |     fn transform(&self, input: A, out: &dyn Fn(B));
   |     ----------------------------------------------- type in trait
...
25 |     fn transform(&self, input: Stdin, out: &dyn Fn(StdinLock)) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(&Lock, std::io::Stdin, &dyn std::ops::Fn(std::io::StdinLock<'_>))`
              found fn pointer `fn(&Lock, std::io::Stdin, &dyn for<'r> std::ops::Fn(std::io::StdinLock<'r>))`
```

Fair enough, the following works:

```rust
impl Lock {
    // desugars into
    // fn transform(input: Stdin, out: &dyn for<'r> Fn(StdinLock<'r>))
    fn transform(input: Stdin, out: &dyn Fn(StdinLock)) {
        (out)(input.lock())
    }
}
```

I don't know how I can include this HRTB in my trait. I've tried, to no avail:

```rust
trait TransformTmp<'r, A, B: 'r> {
    fn transform(input: A, out: &dyn Fn(B));
}

trait TransformTmpAll<A, B>: for<'r> TransformTmp<'r, A, B> {}
```

```
32 | impl<'r> TransformTmp<'r, Stdin, StdinLock<'r>> for Lock {
   |      -- lifetime `'r` defined here
33 |     fn transform(input: Stdin, out: &dyn Fn(StdinLock<'r>)) {
34 |         (out)(input.lock())
   |         ------^^^^^--------
   |         |     |
   |         |     borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `input` is borrowed for `'r`
35 |     }
   |     - `input` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: Have you considered changing the signature of `transform` to `fn transform(&self, input: A, out: impl FnMut(B))`? That would be simpler and more idiomatic, and does not require trait objects or references/lifetimes.